# AutoComplete with backspacing tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an IDE and had asked for some help with getting a special widget that could give autocomplete. Thanks to @BryanOakley [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816574/autocomplete-with-backspacing-tkinter) I was able to get that help. The widget works well but it has a couple issues that I can't seem to figure out on my own. One of these problems is that once the autocomplete code finds a match it inserts the rest of the code and it prevents the user from removing the previous character. It looks like it should work as is given that it puts the insert to where it was left off but when I attempt to remove the last character with the Delete button it doesn't. I am unsure of how to fix this. How could I go about doing this?

The autocomplete Text widget:

```
from tkinter import * 

class AutocompleteText(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callback = kwargs.pop("autocomplete", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = Text(self, font=("Courier New bold", 15), wrap=NONE, undo=True)
        self.text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.text.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self._autocomplete)
        self.text.bind("<Tab>", self._handle_tab)

    def _handle_tab(self, event):
        tag_ranges= self.text.tag_ranges("autocomplete")
        if tag_ranges:
            self.text.mark_set("insert", tag_ranges[1])
            self.text.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")
            self.text.tag_remove("autocomplete", "1.0", "end")
            return "break"

    def _autocomplete(self, event):
        if event.char and self.callback:
            word = self.text.get("insert-1c wordstart", "insert-1c wordend")
            matches = self.callback(word)
            if matches:
                remainder = matches[0][len(word):]
                insert = self.text.index("insert")
                self.text.insert(insert, remainder, ("sel", "autocomplete"))
                self.text.mark_set("insert", insert)


def get_matches(word):
    #Returns possible matches
    #words is a list of almost every keyword and builtin function
    words=["False", "await", "else", "import", "pass", "None", "break", "except", "in", "raise", "True", "class", "finally", "is", "return", "and", "continue", "for", "lambda", "try", "as", "def", "from", "nonlocal", "while", "assert", "del", "global", "not", "with", "async", "elif", "if", "or", "yield", "abs", "all", "any", "ascii", "bin", "bool", "bytearray", "bytes", "callable", "chr", "classmethod", "compile", "complex", "delattr", "dict", "dir", "divmod", "enumerate", "eval", "exec", "filter", "float", "format", "frozenset", "getattr", "globals", "hasattr", "hash", "help", "hex", "id", "input", "int", "isinstance", "issubclass", "iter", "len", "list", "locals", "map", "max", "memoryview", "min", "next", "object", "oct", "open", "ord", "pow", "print", "property", "range", "repr", "reversed", "round", "set", "setattr", "slice", "sorted", "staticmethod", "str", "sum", "super", "tuple", "type", "vars", "zip"]
    matches = [x for x in words if x.startswith(word)]
    return matches

root = Tk()
text = AutocompleteText(root, autocomplete=get_matches)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I want to convert the widget he has into a class with a builtin Frame and then make the Text widget self.text. This would allow me to give the Text widget attributes like font."_ - That's completely unnecessary. You can give the text widget attributes using `self` (ie: `self.configure(font=....)`)

Comment: Please focus on only one question at a time, either converting the widget to a frame, or handling backspace. Don't ask about both at the same time.

Comment: What does _"I want to give the widget backspacing"_  mean? What do you expect to happen when the user presses the backspace key? Have you tried modifying the `if` statement inside of `_autocomplete` in order to also support backspace?

Comment: #BryanOakley I updated the question to clarify. I haven't modified the if statement as it seems find and I can't find where the problem is in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import * 

class AutocompleteText(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callback = kwargs.pop("autocomplete", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = Text(self, font=("Courier New bold", 15), wrap=NONE, undo=True)
        self.text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.text.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self._autocomplete)
        self.text.bind("<Tab>", self._handle_tab)

    def _handle_tab(self, event):
        tag_ranges= self.text.tag_ranges("autocomplete")
        if tag_ranges:
            self.text.mark_set("insert", tag_ranges[1])
            self.text.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")
            self.text.tag_remove("autocomplete", "1.0", "end")
            return "break"

    def _autocomplete(self, event):
        if event.char and self.callback and event.keysym != "BackSpace":
            word = self.text.get("insert-1c wordstart", "insert-1c wordend")
            matches = self.callback(word)
            if matches:
                remainder = matches[0][len(word):]
                insert = self.text.index("insert")
                self.text.insert(insert, remainder, ("sel", "autocomplete"))
                self.text.mark_set("insert", insert)


def get_matches(word):
    #Returns possible matches
    #words is a list of almost every keyword and builtin function
    words=["False", "await", "else", "import", "pass", "None", "break", "except", "in", "raise", "True", "class", "finally", "is", "return", "and", "continue", "for", "lambda", "try", "as", "def", "from", "nonlocal", "while", "assert", "del", "global", "not", "with", "async", "elif", "if", "or", "yield", "abs", "all", "any", "ascii", "bin", "bool", "bytearray", "bytes", "callable", "chr", "classmethod", "compile", "complex", "delattr", "dict", "dir", "divmod", "enumerate", "eval", "exec", "filter", "float", "format", "frozenset", "getattr", "globals", "hasattr", "hash", "help", "hex", "id", "input", "int", "isinstance", "issubclass", "iter", "len", "list", "locals", "map", "max", "memoryview", "min", "next", "object", "oct", "open", "ord", "pow", "print", "property", "range", "repr", "reversed", "round", "set", "setattr", "slice", "sorted", "staticmethod", "str", "sum", "super", "tuple", "type", "vars", "zip"]
    matches = [x for x in words if x.startswith(word)]
    return matches

root = Tk()
text = AutocompleteText(root, autocomplete=get_matches)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This works because when you give an event it has a value to tell what key was pressed. By using this value we can make a backspacing edge case