# Tkinter Text widget not recognizing "<" as part of a word

Tags: python, tkinter, autocomplete

I'm trying to make a simple HTML Editor with Tkinter, with Python 3.10. Right now I'm trying to implement auto-completion using the Tkinter Text widget. The widget checks the word currently typed to see if it matches with any of the HTML tags in `self._tags_list`. And if it does, it auto-completes it.

Code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk


class IDE(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self._tags_list = ['<html></html>', '<head></head>', '<title></title>', '<body></body>', '<h1></h1>',
                           '<h2></h2>', '<h3></h3>', '<h4></h4>', '<h5></h5>', '<h6></h6>', '<p></p>', '<b></b>']

        self.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self._autocomplete)
        self.bind("<Tab>", self._completion, add=True)
        self.bind("<Return>", self._completion, add=True)

    def callback(self, word):
        # Returns possible matches of `word`
        matches = [x for x in self._tags_list if x.startswith(word)]
        return matches

    def _completion(self, _event):
        tag_ranges = self.tag_ranges("autocomplete")
        if tag_ranges:
            self.mark_set("insert", tag_ranges[1])
            self.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")
            self.tag_remove("autocomplete", "1.0", "end")
            return "break"

    def _autocomplete(self, event):
        if event.keysym not in ["Return"] and not self.tag_ranges("sel"):
            self.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")
            self.tag_remove("autocomplete", "1.0", "end")
            word = self.get("insert-1c wordstart", "insert-1c wordend")
            print(f"word: {word}")

            matches = self.callback(word)
            print(f"matches: {matches}")

            if matches:
                remainder = random.choice(matches)[len(word):]
                print(remainder)
                insert = self.index("insert")
                self.insert(insert, remainder, ("sel", "autocomplete"))
                self.mark_set("insert", insert)
                return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Autocomplete")
    window.geometry("500x500")
    text = IDE(window)
    text.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    window.mainloop()
```

Used from [@TRCK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816574/autocomplete-with-backspacing-tkinter).
When I type in the "<" to start an HTML tag, it detects the first possible auto-completion (a random tag from `self._tags_list` minus the "<" at the beginning). However, when I type in a second character, it detects that character as a separate word and does not auto-complete. I've tested it with words not starting with "<" and it worked fine.

For example, terminal output when I type "<h" into the widget:

When I hit "<":

```
word: <
matches: ['<html></html>', '<head></head>', '<title></title>', '<body></body>', '<h1></h1>', '<h2></h2>', '<h3></h3>', '<h4></h4>', '<h5></h5>', '<h6></h6>', '<p></p>', '<b></b>']
remainder: h3></h3>
```

When I add the "h":

```
word: h
matches: []
```

Image of Tkinter window:

[image: Window]

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? I've checked all around and found nothing yet. Sorry if it is obvious, but I am now learning Tkinter. Also if there are any other problems in the code, please tell me.

Comment: Where is maniloop()?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Sorry I forgot to copy it, thanks a lot, it's in now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A word in `wordstart` is defined as

> "a word is either a string of consecutive letter, digit, or underbar (_) characters, or a single character that is none of these types."

when you type more characters after `<`, the `wordstart` starts from the character next to the `<`. You can make this work by adding `-1c` at the end of wordstart

```py
word = self.get("insert -1c wordstart -1c", "insert -1c wordend")
```

By adding

```py
if "<" in word:
    word = word[word.index("<"):]
```

after `word` you can have a slight improvement.

Besides that you also need to exclude BackSpace, Ctrl+a etc from your keysym